# ERROR! MySQL is running but PID file could not be found - MariaDB 10.1 - CentOS 7 - Fresh VM

Tags: mariadb, mariadb-10.1, centos-7

So I'm having a little trouble with a BRAND new VM I just created today to test a Galera Cluster.

What I have done so far is...

1. Download and install the latest CentOS 7 in a VM.
2. Install open-vm-tools and configure SSH
3. Install MariaDB Repo and install MariaDB 10.1 via

   ```
       cat << 'EOL' >/etc/yum.repos.d/MariaDB.repo
       # MariaDB 10.1 CentOS repository list - created 2016-12-21 16:21 UTC
       # http://downloads.mariadb.org/mariadb/repositories/
       [mariadb]
       name = MariaDB
       baseurl = http://yum.mariadb.org/10.1/centos7-amd64
       gpgkey=https://yum.mariadb.org/RPM-GPG-KEY-MariaDB
       gpgcheck=1
       EOL
       yum install MariaDB-server MariaDB-client
   ```

   4. Now I get this error, but I am able to get to the MariaDB CMD Prompt which says its running, but I can't have this error on a brand new setup.

      ```
      [root@localhost ~]# mysql -uroot
      Welcome to the MariaDB monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
      Your MariaDB connection id is 2
      Server version: 10.1.20-MariaDB MariaDB Server

      Copyright (c) 2000, 2016, Oracle, MariaDB Corporation Ab and others.

      Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

      MariaDB [(none)]> exit;
      Bye
      [root@localhost ~]# /etc/init.d/mysql status
      ERROR! MySQL is running but PID file could not be found
      ```

Comment: I've tried upgrading every package on the VM post install of MariaDB, going to try a "pre" upgrade and then install. Thankfully I took a "Vanilla" Snapshot before installing MariaDB!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems the issue was how it is started.

Using the following, all is well!!

```
[root@sql ~]# systemctl start mariadb.service
[root@sql ~]# systemctl enable mariadb.service
[root@sql ~]# /etc/init.d/mysql status
SUCCESS! MySQL running (920)
```

So don't use `/etc/init.d/mysql start` as stated in the install guide...

https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/yum/